# Can I workaround an unrecognized display?

Tags: nvidia, 13.10, resolution, projector

I have an Epson Powerlite 8350; it's not recognized on my laptop, which has an nVidia Quadro 2000M and Ubuntu 13.10, so that the screen resolution is limited to 1024x768.

This happens with both the nouveau and the nvidia-319 drivers.
In the BIOS, I've configured the system to use only the discrete graphics, so I don't have Optimus-related problems.

This is somewhat strange, because I remember that on 13.04, the display was recognized.

Is there a way to workaround this problem, to have access to the full resolution (1920x1080), also considering that I sometimes hotswap the display with another (which is correctly recognized)?

Answer (score 1):

I found pointers for a possible solution here:

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/X/Config/Resolution#Adding_undetected_resolutions